# Check all the values in a Julia array?

Tags: arrays, julia

How can I check all the values in a Julia array at once? Let's say I have an array like `a=[3,4,6,10,55,31,9,10]` How can I check if the array has any values greater than 10? Or how can I check if there are repeating values (like the 10 that is contained twice in the sample? I know I can write loops to check this, but I assume Julia has a faster way to check all the values at once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The functions `any` and `count` do this:

```
julia> a = [3,4,6,10,55,31,9,10]
8-element Array{Int64,1}:
  3
  4
  6
 10
 55
 31
  9
 10

julia> any(x->x==3, a)
true

julia> count(x->x==10, a)
2
```

However the performance will probably be about the same as a loop, since loops in julia are fast (and these functions are themselves implemented in julia in the standard library).

If the problem has more structure you can get big speedups. For example if the vector is sorted you can use `searchsorted` to find matching values with binary search.

Comment: Great that gets me the first part. But could I have you modify your answer a bit? I only used 10 as an example. But I want to find ANY repeating values. Like a=[1,4,4] would return TRUE while a=[1,2,3] would return FALSE

Comment: Wait, I think I got this. I can combine the answer you gave and then use the unique() function to get me the second part of that I needed. Thanks!!!

Comment: @JeffBezanson: Just if people come here when searching for this (as I did). Couldn't one use `.==` instead of `x->x==3`? `any(a.==3)` seems to work for me. Or is there a good reason not to use it?

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this had been implemented at the time of previous answers, but the most concise way now would be:

```
all(a .> 10)
```

As Chris Rackauckas mentioned, `a .> 10` returns an array of booleans, and then `all` simply checks that all values are `true`. Equivalent of Python's `any` and `all`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use broadcasted operations. In some cases it's nicer syntax than `any` and `count`, in other cases it can be less obvious what it's doing:

```
boola = a.>10 # Returns an Array{Bool}, true at any value >10
minimum(boola) # Returns false if any are <10
sum(a-10 .== 0) # Finds all values equal to 10, sums to get a count
```